# Viewpager: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener - MotionEvent e1 in onFling method is always null. [ScrollView inside the Fragment for ViewPager]

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am getting  MotionEvent e1 always null in onFling method.

My observation is that - When the fragment UI has scrollview, issue arrives. Whereas, if there is no ScrollView, everything works perfectly fine.

My adapter -

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Returns total number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return dataModelForPager.size();
        }

        // Returns the fragment to display for that page
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            PageControlModel ttm = dataModelForPager.get(position);

            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                   // vpPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
                    //return StaticMobileFragment.newInstance(position, ttm.page_name, ttm.page_id);
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1", vpPager);
                case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2", vpPager);
                case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3",vpPager);
                case 3: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance(3, "Page # 4",vpPager);
                case 4: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance(4, "Page # 5",vpPager);
                default:
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance(100, "Page # 100",vpPager);
            }
        }

        // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
```

Fragment XML -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have added scrollview for TextView just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after so many days and hours of work I came across the solution.

1. Implement `View.OnTouchListener, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` in the same activity instead of creating a different custom class for `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`.
2. Create an object of GestureDetector on onCreate method as -

   gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(SecondActivity.this,this);
3. Use the methods -

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
   {
       return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
   }

   public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
   {
       return true;
   }

   public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float
           velocityX, float velocityY)
   {
       boolean result = false;
       try {
           float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
           float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
           if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
               if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                   if (diffX > 0) {
                       onSwipeRight();
                   } else {
                       onSwipeLeft();
                   }
               }
           } else {
               // onTouch(e);
           }
       } catch (Exception exception) {
           exception.printStackTrace();
       }
       return result;
   }

   public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
   {
   }

   public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float
           distanceX, float distanceY)
   {
       return true;
   }

   public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e)
   {
   }

   public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
   {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
   }

   public void onSwipeRight() {
       Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Previous", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   public void onSwipeLeft() {
       Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   ```
4. Finally the most important thing - to use ScrollView inside ViewPager

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
       return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(ev);
   }
   ```

I hope this will be useful for someone.

Reference link - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/n9-wPQlZ4pk